# Jenkins Pipeline Conditional Stage based on Environment Variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a Jenkins (v2.126) Declarative syntax pipeline, which has stages with when() clauses checking the value of an environment variable. Specifically I want to set a Jenkins job parameter (so 'build with parameters', not pipeline parameters) and have this determine if a stage is executed.

I have stage code like this:

```
stage('plan') {
  when {
     environment name: ExecuteAction, value: 'plan'
  }
  steps {
     sh 'cd $dir && $tf plan'
  }
}
```

The parameter name is ExecuteAction. However, when ExecuteAction is set via a Job "Choice" parameter to: plan, this stage does not run. I can see the appropriate value is coming in via environment variable by adding this debug stage:

```
stage('debug') {
  steps {
     sh 'echo "ExecuteAction = $ExecuteAction"'
     sh 'env'
  }
}
```

And I get Console output like this:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (debug)
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ echo 'ExecuteAction = plan'
ExecuteAction = plan
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ env
...
ExecuteAction=plan
...
```

I am using the when declarative syntax from [Jenkins book pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), at about mid-page, under the when section, built-in conditions.

Jenkins is running on Gnu/Linux.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Duh! You need to quote the environment variable's name in the when clause.

```
stage('plan') {
  when {
     environment name: 'ExecuteAction', value: 'plan'
  }
  steps {
     sh 'cd $dir && $tf plan'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe you need to use ***params*** instead of ***environment***. Try the following:

```
when {
     expression { params.ExecuteAction == 'plan' }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. The original question was answered regarding use of environment variables. But a parameter should do the trick too.

Comment: Just to complete this conversation, @KevinBuchs's code works because `params` are also accessible as `env` vars. I personally find the syntax of the `environment` when-clause unintuitive, so it's nice to have two options.